# Android decrypt RSA returned grabled code before meaningful result

Tags: android, rsa

I am decrypting RSA enctypted message on Android, it returned

`,+�Y����oz���L�͡�Jp:S�&-A^����\ԅ<�)�B�5Nf�J
�$�^E�z<��yE�l����c�
���T�+�,yw�3愶���U�WM���g�$����123`

123 is what i encrypted, however when i run same decryption code on Java server, it can return corret result, here are my decrypte code.

```
public static byte[] decryptByPrivateKey(byte[] encryptedData, String privateKey)
            throws Exception {
        byte[] keyBytes = Base64.decode(privateKey);
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec pkcs8KeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(KEY_ALGORITHM);
        Key privateK = keyFactory.generatePrivate(pkcs8KeySpec);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(keyFactory.getAlgorithm());
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateK);
        int inputLen = encryptedData.length;
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int offSet = 0;
        byte[] cache;
        int i = 0;
        while (inputLen - offSet > 0) {
            if (inputLen - offSet > MAX_DECRYPT_BLOCK) {
                cache = cipher.doFinal(encryptedData, offSet, MAX_DECRYPT_BLOCK);
            } else {
                cache = cipher.doFinal(encryptedData, offSet, inputLen - offSet);
            }
            out.write(cache, 0, cache.length);
            i++;
            offSet = i * MAX_DECRYPT_BLOCK;
        }
        byte[] decryptedData = out.toByteArray();
        out.close();
        return decryptedData;
    }
```

Comment: And where is the code the calculates `MAX_DECRYPT_BLOCK`?

Comment: @JamesKPolk it is hard coded 128

Comment: And what makes you think 128 is correct? What if I told you 128 is too large to guarantee unique decryption? And it should certainly be a function of the key size, not hard-coded.

Answer (score -1):

Use Base64 with NO_WRAP to decode and encode.

```
Base64.encodeToString(encryptedBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP)
Base64.decode(encryptedData, Base64.NO_WRAP)
```

Comment: What makes you think `encryptedBytes` is base64 encoded in the first place?